# Bootstrap modal not trigerring after using the pagination from the datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using Bootstrap and Datatable. Modal is opened when i click the details button. In the first page pagination when i click the details button the modal window is opening properly, but when i am on the second page the modal window is not triggering. Can someone help me on the same.
Here is my code

my javascript for datatable is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.view_data').click(function(){  
       var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       var data = table.row( this ).data();
       $.ajax({  
            url:"search_details.php",  
            method:"post",  
            data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#search_detail').html(data);  
                 $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
            }  
       });  
  });  
});
```

search_details.php which is the php page getting the record details

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST["employee_id"]))  
{  
    include('../db.php');
  $output = '';  

  $query = "SELECT * FROM patent_search WHERE id = '".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";  
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
  $output .= '  
  <div class="table-responsive">  
       <table id="prodlist" class="table table-bordered">';  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {
```

This is the details button in the datatable which is trigerring the Modal

```
 <input type="button" name="view" value="Details" id="<? echo $row["id"]; ?> class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" />
```

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Upadate:** This is what worked in OP's case:

```
$('body').on('click', '.view_data', function () {
  // your code here...
});
```

**Original Answer:**

Try this:

```
$('#datatable-default').on('click', '.view_data', function () {
  // your code here...
});
```

**Expalination:**

The HTML for second row is generated by `DataTables` **after the click** has been registered. For details have a look at [jQuery Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: No its not working. If you can see my search_details.php, i have not used tbody . Do you thats the problem?

Comment: No its not working. And iam not seeing any error in the console as well.

Comment: did you make sure to **use the ID of parent table (inside which the button is present)**?

Comment: also, can you share HTML for parent table?

Comment: This is the parent table (data table)where iam using the details button to open the Modal window.. <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-default">

Comment: This is the table which iam using in search_details.php to fetch the details record..<table id="details" class="table table-bordered">';

Comment: then your code your look like `$('#datatable-default').on('click', '.view_data',....`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: i think i have to do some different approach. i mean rephrasing the complete code i guess.

Comment: I have created an example, can you have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ypkxqnzh/)?

Comment: Thank you so much. When i use this its workng. $('body').on('click','.view_data',function(){